# How to create JAR-file from every .java file in package

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a package `plugins` and there are some java sources:

```
plugins - | - Plugin1.java
          | - Plugin2.java
          | - ............
          | - PluginN.java
```

I need to compile every plugin in jar file. I want to end up with
plugin1.jar, plugin2.jar and so on.
Is is possible to do with maven-assembly plugin or maven-jar? 
Or I need to develop my own maven plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with maven-jar-plugin

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId> 
      <executions> 
        <execution> 
          <id>make-plugin1-jar</id> 
          <phase>prepare-package</phase> 
          <goals> 
            <goal>jar</goal> 
          </goals> 
          <configuration> 
            <includes> 
              <include>com/myapp/plugins/Plugin1.class</include> 
            </includes> 
            <finalName>plugin1.jar</finalName> 
          </configuration> 
        </execution> 
        <execution> 
          <id>make-plugin2-jar</id> 
          <goals> 
            <goal>jar</goal> 
          </goals> 
          <phase>prepare-package</phase> 
          <configuration> 
            <includes> 
              <include>com/myapp/plugins/Plugin2.class</include> 
            </includes> 
            <finalName>plugin2.jar</finalName> 
          </configuration> 
        </execution> 
      </executions> 
    </plugin>
```

Comment: The class names are hardcoded for two plugins. I need as many jars as there are in the folder. I don't know what the classes would be and how much.

Comment: The purpose of a jar is to package many classes so this plugin was designed to include whole classes from a package like <include>com/myapp/plugins/*</include> resulting a single jar with all classes in package plugins.